# UITableView ReloadData Animate Cell UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewanimation

In my tableview I need to animate the UI of every cell as the tableview reloads its data.

This needs to a custom animation, not just a fade or default transition.

For example, When tapping the 'Edit' button, in my view, the tableview reloads and each cell updates its UI for this new edit mode.

However, during this reload I have tried using a `UIView` animation block to update a constraint on a `UILabel` in my cells, but it will not animate.

Here is the code I run when I call `reloadData` on my tableview. This is called in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^
    {
        //does not animate
        _lblContainerLeftConstraint.constant = 18;
        [self setNeedsLayout];

        //does animate
        _reorderIcon.alpha = 0.5f;

    } completion:nil];
```

Comment: I think you need to do this in `willDisplayCell`. Set the new constraint value before the animation block and call `[cell.contentView setNeedsLayout]`. Then  add `[cell.contentView layoutIfNeeded]` in the animation block which should animate the constraint change over your time period.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks @RoryMcKinnel Drop an official answer in below and I'll tick you off if you like.

Comment: Glad it worked. Posted as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do this in `willDisplayCell` rather than `cellForRowAtIndexPath` since that is called just before display which is as close as you can get to the point it actually appears on screen.

Then set the new constraint value before the animation block and also call `[cell.contentView setNeedsLayout]` to indicate that layout is needed on the cell content.

Finally only add `[cell.contentView layoutIfNeeded]` and your alpha change in the animation block which should animate the constraint change over your time period.